# How do you read command line arguments for the updated C++/WinRT/XAML UWP apps

Tags: c++-winrt

I have not been able to find any documentation on how to process the command line arguments of a C++/WinRT, XAML app.

In Visual Studio 15.9.6 the application properties do provide a way to enter command line arguments during the development effort, but no way to process them.

For a Blank App (C++/WinRT) template, the App.cpp file has the following:

```
/// <summary>
/// Initializes the singleton application object.  This is the first line of authored code
/// executed, and as such is the logical equivalent of main() or WinMain().
/// </summary>
App::App()
{
   ...
}
```

wherein main() and WinMain() are mentioned.

I would expect to have some number of main() or WinMain() read arguments which would then be processed by the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to get the command line arguments in a UWP XAML application. The natural way to get the command line is to override the [Application::OnLaunched](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.onlaunched#Windows_UI_Xaml_Application_OnLaunched_Windows_ApplicationModel_Activation_LaunchActivatedEventArgs_) member, that gets passed a [LaunchActivatedEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.activation.launchactivatedeventargs) argument. Its [Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.activation.launchactivatedeventargs.arguments) property holds the command line.

Alternatively, you can query the OS: [GetCommandLineW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156.aspx) returns the command line from anywhere inside the application. (Note, that [CommandLineToArgvW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-commandlinetoargvw) to parse the command line into individual arguments is not available in a UWP application.)

If you do need the command line decomposed into individual arguments, you'll have to go with a Microsoft specific extension to its C Runtime implementation: [`__argc` and `__wargv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/argc-argv-wargv) provide the decomposed command line arguments the same way you would get them through a standard `main` entry point.

Comment: Why do you suggest **overridding** `Application::OnLaunched()` rather than just parsing the `LaunchActivatedEventArgs` argument?

Comment: @IInspectable How do we pass those argument(s) from `App.xaml.cs` file to the `MainPage.xaml.cs`? Suppose I pass `Hello World` to command line. The `App.xaml.cs` file reads that argument (as you described above). Now through my code, I want to pass that `Hello World` string to `MainPage.xaml.cs` file so I can assign it to, say, `TextBlock.Text` property. I'm using `C#`. Please advise.

Comment: @nam I'm not familiar with C# or the .NET framework, or how it maps onto the Windows Runtime.

Comment: @use I'm not sure how you would parse the `LaunchActivatedEventArgs` without providing your own implementation of `Application::OnLaunched()`. Providing your custom implementation for an interface method is implemented as a function overload in C++/WinRT.